# How to calculate eigenvector centrality for specific nodes, r, igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I'm using the igraph package in r.
I have an undirected, weighted network of about 1000 nodes and i want the eigenvector centrality for a list of about 100 of them

```
evcent (graph, directed = FALSE, scale = TRUE, weights = NULL,
     options = igraph.arpack.default)
```

returns all 1000 ev centralities.

Is there a way to specify which nodes it returns ev centrality for?

Comment: The question is unclear. What do you mean by `eigenvector centrality for a list of about 100 of them`?

Comment: A reproducible example (obviously with a smaller number of nodes) would help.

Comment: importantnodes=c("a","d","f")
with the entire alphabet being all notes in the graph, g is graph object
evcent(g,weights=E(g)$weight)$vector gives:
a
.1
b
.05
....

in small xamples i can use names() to match them but i'd like to have the output vector to only have the nodes i want

Comment: In that case , it is just x[which(letters %in% c("a","d","f"))] where x is the result of evcent(..). But all this could be easily tested if you give an example with the exoected result.

Answer (score 1):

```
ev <- evcent(graph, ...)$vector
ev[important]
```